# How to store HTML attributes that trigger javascript commands properly to mysql using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

I have problems when saving html5 data from a page into mysql through an ajax request and trying to retrieve it back with ajax. HTML attributes that trigger some javascript such as

`<onload>` or `<iframe>` will be stored as `<on<x>load>` and `<if<x>rame>` in the database and thus screw up the page when loading it.

Here's a short description of what I am trying to accomplish: I want registered users to have the ability to highlight text on my site and get the highlighted text back after refreshing the page, relogging etc.

What I have done so far: I implemented a javascript highlight library on my server that allows users to highlight text. That works well.

By clicking a button, those data are then saved into mysql through jquery ajax post. See specific code here:

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
//saves highlighted data in var "highlighted"
$('#savehighlights').click(function() {
    var highlighted = $('.tabcontent.content1').html();

    //send data to server
    $.ajax({
        url: 'highlight.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {highlighted: highlighted},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Saving the data to mysql works generally, but it looks as if certain commands are disabled through the process (e.g. `onload` becomes `on<x>load`5). The data are stored in the database as longtext and utf8_bin. I also tried blob, but  problem remains. I also tried different dataTypes with Ajax such as 'text' and 'script'. 'Text' causes the same problem and 'script doesn't work at all. I also tried the ajax .serialize function, but no luck either.

I really don't know what to do about it and I am not sure what is causing the problem, Ajax or mysql? I was searching the web for an answer, including many articles in stackoverflow (which normally always give me the answer), but this time I am stuck. Either I don't know enough about it to look for the right question, or I just don't have any luck this time. So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was requested to add some more information. Here it is:

I am actually doing this on my local server (localhost) with XAMP, so security issues should not be a problem, right? If it is of any help, I am doing this in a Tiki Wiki CMS. The php script  that is called through ajax (highlight.php) is the following:

```
require_once ('tiki-setup.php');
include_once ('lib/highlights/highlightslib.php');
$highlighted = $_POST['highlighted'];
$highlightslib->save_highlights($user, $highlighted);
```

The highlightslib library is here:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], basename(__FILE__)) !== false) {
  header("location: index.php");
  exit;
}

class HighlightsLib extends TikiLib
{

    function save_highlights($user, $highlighted) {
    $saveHighlights = $this->table('tiki_user_highlights');
    $saveHighlights->insert
        (array(
            'user' =>$user, 
            'highlightId' =>'',
            'data' =>$highlighted,
            'created' =>$this->now,
        )
    );
    return true;
    }
};

$highlightslib = new HighlightsLib;
```

Comment: Can we see what you are doing on the server side? You may be manipulating the data in some way.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall or on a public wifi connection? There may be a layer of "security" in place between you and the server.

Comment: I updated my question and it know includes more information. Just very briefly I want to comment on your question, Joe. I am still developing, so I am working on my local server with XAMPP. So, no firewall or public wifi connection is causing this.